# PHP: create 2 dimensional array from multidimensional array with value as key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I try to create a new array from an complex array.
If there's no easy solution, every hint would help to search more successful.

I have this complex array (shortened a lot) and want to build a new 2 dimensional array:

```
array (
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
    [category] => array (
        [key3] => value3
        [key4] => array (
            [small] => value6
            [large] => value7 
            )
        [items] => array (
            [0] => array (
                [aTag] => #PU2RRL
                [name] => 3PL
                [position] => 25
                [versions] => array (
                    [0] => array (
                        [bTag] => #KF67RL
                        [color] => blue
                        [id] => 001
                        )
                    [1] => array (
                        [bTag] => #Z8TR4
                        [color] => red
                        [id] => 002
                        )
                )
            )
            [1] => array (
              ...
```

This is the array I want to create:

```
array(
  [001] => array (
    [aTag] => #PU2RRL
    [name] => 3PL
    [position] => 25
    [bTag] => #KF67RL
    [color] => blue
  )
  [002] => array (
    [aTag] => #PU2RRL
    [name] => 3PL
    [position] => 25
    [bTag] => #Z8TR4
    [color] => blue))
```

With ID as key and this values:

```
$itemAll = array(
  $array[category][items][0][versions][0][id]  => array(
    "aTag" => $array[category][items][0][aTag],
    "name" =>  $array[category][items][0][name],
    "position" =>  $array[category][items][0][position],
    "bTag" => $array[category][items][0][versions][0][bTag],
    "color" => $array[category][items][0][versions][0][color],
  )
);
```

I have no clue how to create this array with foreach loops for "items" and versions with the ID as primary key, any hints?

---

EDIT: huge thanks to @DeeDuu! Because I had multiple items I added another foreach:

```
$new_array = array();
// i have multiple items, so I removed [0]:
$items = $array["category"]["items"];
// added another foreach
foreach ($items as $item) {
  // changed $items to $item
  $shared_properties = array(
  "aTag" => $item["aTag"],
  "name" => $item["name"],
  "position" => $item["position"]
  );
  // changed $items to $item
  foreach ($item["versions"] as $version) {
  $specific_properties = array(
      "bTag" => $version["bTag"],
      "color" => $version["color"]
  );
  $new_entry = array_merge(
      $shared_properties,
      $specific_properties
  );
  $new_array[$version["id"]] = $new_entry;  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, something like the following should work.

```
 // This is the target array where we will save the recombinated data
 $new_array = array();

 // Store the relevant subarray in a new variable;
 // This makes the subsequent code shorter
 $items = $array["category"]["items"][0];

 // This gives the data that will be common to all the new entries,
 // for all versions seem to share aTag, name and position
 $shared_properties = array(
     "aTag" => $items["aTag"],
     "name" => $items["name"],
     "position" => $items["position"]
 );

 // Alright, let's loop over the versions
 foreach ($items["versions"] as $version) {
     // Another array for the data that is specific
     // to the version we're currently looking at
     $specific_properties = array(
         "bTag" => $version["bTag"],
         "color" => $version["color"]
     );

     // The new entry is a combination of the shared and the
     // specific properties; array_merge will do that for us
     $new_entry = array_merge(
         $shared_properties,
         $specific_properties
     );

     // Now add to the new array
     $new_array[$version["id"]] = $new_entry;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, missed notification, HUGE thanks, worked perfect.I have multiple items, so I added another foreach

Comment: @LeoRon Glad I could help you! Since this has solved your problem, please vote and accept the answer.

Comment: have accepted and voted (my first question here, still learning), my vote though won't show up, have less than 15 reputation